# Помогите записать в БД select option не value, а текст <option>текст</option>

Tags: php, javascript, база-данных, html-select

Добрый день. Стала задача записать в бд выбранный текст который расположен между `<option>текст</option>`

```
<select >
    <option value="0">текст который нужно записать в бд</option>
    <option value="1">текст который нужно записать в бд 2</option>
</select>
```

Так как не силен в в этом прошу помочь. Нвшел вот такое

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#selectID").change(function() {
        $("#value").text($(this).val());
        $("#text").text($("#selectID option:selected").text());
    });
});
</script>
```

но как в переменную это запихнуть не знаю.
Мне надо или вывести в переменную что бы в инпут засунуть или прямо со скрипта записать, разницы нет так как это всё скрыто.

Comment: кажется ты все уже сделал, осталось только ajax запрос послать скрипту PHP, который и сохранит в базу данные.

Comment: select создаешь сам? если да то просто убери `value`. или так же можно через `js` убрать все `value`.

Comment: value мне надо для записи в бд но и само содержимое нужно тоже записать

Answer (score 0):

кажется ты все уже сделал, осталось только ajax запрос послать скрипту PHP, который и сохранит в базу данные. Смотрим http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#selectID").change(function() {
        $("#value").text($(this).val());
        $("#text").text($("#selectID option:selected").text());

        // добавляем
        var text = $("#selectID option:selected").text();
        $.ajax({
          method: "POST",
          url: "save_text.php",
          data: { text: text }
        });

    });
});
</script>
```

Ставь дизлайк если хочешь, но тут не сайт туториалов, а ответов на вопросы. Ответ я дал. (см комментарии).